# In React - How to get value from .sh(Shell Script) file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sh

I have .sh file like :

```
echo "Hello"
```

Which outputs :

```
Hello
```

---

**Here is the query :**

> What I want to achieve is, to get output from the .sh file and use it in
>   my react application.

I have searched for npm packages but can't find any useful

Comment: as in node you can use child_process module to run your shell script and save its output in some variable

Comment: @FarhanYaseen, sounds interesting

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html Here is the complete detail

Comment: @FarhanYaseen, I dont think that will help me from react side

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are not on Windows machine, you can write simple Node Express server, which can receive GET request, then execute your shell script with Node's built-in `child_process.exec()` and then send response containing stdout, which, in this case, will be your shell script's output - "Hello"

Code for the server. 'static' folder contains index.html and index.js, code for last is below this:

```
const express = require('express')
const { exec } = require('child_process')
const { join } = require('path')

const port = process.env.PORT || 24587
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'static')))

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  exec(join(__dirname, 'hello.sh'), (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ output: null, error: err.message })
    }

    res.status(200).json({ output: stdout, error: null })
  })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('server listening on port', port)
})
```

Example code for the client (you can also wrap React around this code because the only thing you need is XHR made here with the help of `fetch`):

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn') // <button id="btn">get</button>
const result = document.querySelector('#result') // <div id="result"></div>

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (self.fetch) {
    fetch('/hello')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        result.innerText = data.output
      })
      .catch(data => {
        result.innerText = data.error
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, I think this will work, but I don't want to call any XHR,any idea?

Comment: @VivekDoshi you want to call shell script directly from React?

Comment: @VivekDoshi I'm trying to say, that you can't evaluate anything except javascript in the browser. Of course, you can load shell script file on the client, which implies you to make AJAX request to this local file, then write f.e. regex to extract all lines that start with 'echo' from that file, then parse this lines to get kind of placeholders

Comment: @VivekDoshi and, of course, if you are using React with Electron or something similar, you can simply refactor my solution, because Electron itself provides all Node.js functionality

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put output to any file (`echo $var > $destdir` or using `sed`), read this file using nodejs and for example pass value through ajax request to react.